# PHP: passing php variables as arguments?

Tags: php

In my php code I need to invoke a script and passing it some arguments. How can I pass php variables (as arguments) ?

```
$string1="some value";
$string2="some other value";
header('Location: '...script.php?arg1=$string1&arg2=$string2');
```

thanks

Comment: It should work exactly as you show (as long as it's a valid string, for which you would need to remove the second `'`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
header('Location: ...script.php?arg1=' . $string1 . '&arg2=' . $string2);
```

Comment: Not worth a new answer, but double quotes are also possible: `header("Location: http://example.com/script.php?arg1=$string1&arg2=$string2");`

Answer (score 4):

Either via string concatenation:

```
header('Location: script.php?arg1=' . urlencode($string1) . '&arg2=' . urlencode($string2));
```

Or string interpolation

```
$string1=urlencode("some value");
$string2=urlencode("some other value");
header("Location: script.php?arg1={$string1}&arg2={$string2}");
```

Personally, I prefer the second style. It's far easier on the eyes and less chance of a misplaced quote and/or `.`, and with any decent syntax highlighting editor, the variables will be colored differently than the rest of the string.

The urlencode() portion is required if your values have any kind of url-metacharacters in them (spaces, ampersands, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the function [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
$query = http_build_query(array('arg1' => $string, 'arg2' => $string2));

header("Location: http://www.example.com/script.php?" . $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/script.php?arg1=$string1&arg2=$string2");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but wrap a urlencode() incase there is anything funny breaking the url:

```
header('Location: '...script.php?'.urlencode("arg1=".$string1."&arg2=".$string2).');
```